# WP_Query inside foreach loop returning same value for all options

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach

I have the below below query which is getting the correct posts based on the chosen filter, but it displays the same result for all options.

The foreach loop is based on a taxonomy which displays columns representing each day of the week: Monday – Sunday.

**For example, it's returning:**

Monday: Post one
Tuesday: Post one
Wednesday: Post one
...

**But really it should be returning:**

Monday: Post one, Post two
Tuesday: Post three
Wednesday: Post four 
...

Whats the best way to filter WP_Query based on the two taxonomies and also display the query inside foreach loops.

If anyone can point me in thr right direction that would be great. I've spent days trying different options with no luck! The only way I can get it to work as it should is by removing the foreach loop completely which I can't do as I need the columns of the week.

```
add_action('wp_ajax_classfilter', 'load_posts_by_ajax_callback');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_classfilter', 'load_posts_by_ajax_callback');

function load_posts_by_ajax_callback() {

  check_ajax_referer('load_more_posts', 'security');

  $calendarDays = get_terms([
    'taxonomy' => 'calendar-day',
    'hide_empty' => false,
  ]);

  foreach($calendarDays as $day) {

$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'calendar',
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'meta_key' => 'classes_entry_start_time',
  'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
  'order' => 'ASC',
  'tax_query' => array(
    array(
      'taxonomy' => 'calendar-day',
      'field' => 'id',
      'terms' => $day->term_id
    )
  )
);

if( isset( $_POST['theClass'] ) )
$args['tax_query'] = array(
  array(
    'taxonomy' => 'calendar-class-type',
    'field' => 'id',
    'terms' => $_POST['theClass']
  )
);

$loop = new WP_Query($args);

if($loop->have_posts()) {
  echo '<div class="classes-col">';
  echo '<strong>' . $day->name . '</strong>';
  echo '<ul>';
  while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
    get_part('classes-item', ['classesEntry' => get_field('classes_entry')]);
  endwhile;
  wp_reset_postdata();
  echo '</ul>';
  echo '</div>';
} 
else {
  echo '<div class="classes-col">';
  echo '<strong>' . $day->name . '</strong>';
  echo '</div>';
}

  }

wp_die();
}
```

Comment: Is no one able to help? : /

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested in how to achieve the result for the question I posted, I managed to work it out!

As the correct results we're being displayed, but for each iteration of the foreach loop rather than the specific day, I managed to get the results to display/hide by using if (is_object_in_term($class->ID, 'calendar-day', 'monday') && $day->term_id == 6) . is_object_in_term checks if the $taxonomy are checked against the object’s terms’ term_ids, names and slugs and $day->term_id for each of the days. If it doesn't then nothing is displayed.

I've had to hardcode each day of the week and the code to generate the result. I know this isn't the best D.R.Y approach, but at the moment i'm happy with the current win!

```
add_action('wp_ajax_classfilter', 'load_posts_by_ajax_callback');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_classfilter', 'load_posts_by_ajax_callback');

function load_posts_by_ajax_callback() {

  check_ajax_referer('load_more_posts', 'security');

  $days = get_terms([
    'taxonomy' => 'calendar-day'
  ]);

  // Loop over days of the week
  foreach ($days as $day ) {

    $classesTable .= '<div class="response classes-col">';

    $classesTable .= '<strong>' . $day->name . '</strong>'; // Day name

    // Query arguments based on day of the week
    $args = array(
      'post_type' => 'calendar',
      'meta_key' => 'classes_entry_start_time',
      'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
      'order' => 'ASC',
      'numberposts' => '-1',
      'tax_query' => array(
        array(
          'taxonomy' => 'calendar-day',
          'field' => 'id',
          'terms' =>  $day->term_id
          // 'terms' => array('6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12')
        )
      ),
    );

    if(isset( $_POST['theClass'])) {
      $args['tax_query'] = array(
        array(
          'taxonomy' => 'calendar-class-type',
          'field' => 'id',
          'terms' => $_POST['theClass']
        )
      );
    }

    $query_classes = get_posts( $args );
    $classesArray = array();

    // Loop over query classes posts
    foreach ($query_classes as $key => $class ) {

      // Check if object has term: Monday
      if (is_object_in_term($class->ID, 'calendar-day', 'monday') && $day->term_id == 6):
        // $classesArray[] .= 'YES';
        $start_time = get_field('classes_entry_start_time', $class);
        $end_time = get_field('classes_entry_end_time', $class);
        $classesEntry = get_field('classes_entry', $class);
        // Create class item
        $classesArray[] .= '<li>';
        $classesArray[] .= '<a href="' . $classesEntry['booking_app_link'] . '" target="_blank" class="classes-item">';
        $classesArray[] .= '<span>' . $classesEntry['start_time'] . '</span>';
        $classesArray[] .= '<span>' . $class->post_title . '</span>';
        $classesArray[] .= '<span>' . $classesEntry['duration'] . '</span>';
        $terms = get_the_terms( $class->ID , 'calendar-class-type' );
        if ($terms): foreach ( $terms as $term ):
        $classesArray[] .= '<span>' . $term->name . '</span>';
        endforeach; endif; 
        $classesArray[] .= '</a>';
        $classesArray[] .= '</li>';
      else: 
        // Show nothing
        // $classesArray[] .= 'NO';
      endif;

      // Check if object has term: Tuesday
      if (is_object_in_term($class->ID, 'calendar-day', 'tuesday') && $day->term_id == 7):
        // $classesArray[] .= 'YES';
        $start_time = get_field('classes_entry_start_time', $class);
        $end_time = get_field('classes_entry_end_time', $class);
        $classesEntry = get_field('classes_entry', $class);
        // Create class item
        $classesArray[] .= '<li>';
        $classesArray[] .= '<a href="' . $classesEntry['booking_app_link'] . '" target="_blank" class="classes-item">';
        $classesArray[] .= '<span>' . $classesEntry['start_time'] . '</span>';
        $classesArray[] .= '<span>' . $class->post_title . '</span>';
        $classesArray[] .= '<span>' . $classesEntry['duration'] . '</span>';
        $terms = get_the_terms( $class->ID , 'calendar-class-type' );
        if ($terms): foreach ( $terms as $term ):
        $classesArray[] .= '<span>' . $term->name . '</span>';
        endforeach; endif; 
        $classesArray[] .= '</a>';
        $classesArray[] .= '</li>';
      else :
        // Show nothing
        // $classesArray[] .= 'NO';
      endif;

      // Check if object has term: Wednesday
      if (is_object_in_term($class->ID, 'calendar-day', 'wednesday') && $day->term_id == 8):
        // $classesArray[] .= 'YES';
        $start_time = get_field('classes_entry_start_time', $class);
        $end_time = get_field('classes_entry_end_time', $class);
        $classesEntry = get_field('classes_entry', $class);
        // Create class item
        $classesArray[] .= '<li>';
        $classesArray[] .= '<a href="' . $classesEntry['booking_app_link'] . '" target="_blank" class="classes-item">';
        $classesArray[] .= '<span>' . $classesEntry['start_time'] . '</span>';
        $classesArray[] .= '<span>' . $class->post_title . '</span>';
        $classesArray[] .= '<span>' . $classesEntry['duration'] . '</span>';
        $terms = get_the_terms( $class->ID , 'calendar-class-type' );
        if ($terms): foreach ( $terms as $term ):
        $classesArray[] .= '<span>' . $term->name . '</span>';
        endforeach; endif; 
        $classesArray[] .= '</a>';
        $classesArray[] .= '</li>';
      else :
        // Show nothing
        // $classesArray[] .= 'NO';
      endif;

      // Check if object has term: Thursday
      if (is_object_in_term($class->ID, 'calendar-day', 'thursday') && $day->term_id == 9):
        // $classesArray[] .= 'YES';
        $start_time = get_field('classes_entry_start_time', $class);
        $end_time = get_field('classes_entry_end_time', $class);
        $classesEntry = get_field('classes_entry', $class);
        // Create class item
        $classesArray[] .= '<li>';
        $classesArray[] .= '<a href="' . $classesEntry['booking_app_link'] . '" target="_blank" class="classes-item">';
        $classesArray[] .= '<span>' . $classesEntry['start_time'] . '</span>';
        $classesArray[] .= '<span>' . $class->post_title . '</span>';
        $classesArray[] .= '<span>' . $classesEntry['duration'] . '</span>';
        $terms = get_the_terms( $class->ID , 'calendar-class-type' );
        if ($terms): foreach ( $terms as $term ):
        $classesArray[] .= '<span>' . $term->name . '</span>';
        endforeach; endif; 
        $classesArray[] .= '</a>';
        $classesArray[] .= '</li>';
      else :
        // Show nothing
        // $classesArray[] .= 'NO';
      endif;

      // Check if object has term: Friday
      if (is_object_in_term($class->ID, 'calendar-day', 'friday') && $day->term_id == 10):
        // $classesArray[] .= 'YES';
        $start_time = get_field('classes_entry_start_time', $class);
        $end_time = get_field('classes_entry_end_time', $class);
        $classesEntry = get_field('classes_entry', $class);
        // Create class item
        $classesArray[] .= '<li>';
        $classesArray[] .= '<a href="' . $classesEntry['booking_app_link'] . '" target="_blank" class="classes-item">';
        $classesArray[] .= '<span>' . $classesEntry['start_time'] . '</span>';
        $classesArray[] .= '<span>' . $class->post_title . '</span>';
        $classesArray[] .= '<span>' . $classesEntry['duration'] . '</span>';
        $terms = get_the_terms( $class->ID , 'calendar-class-type' );
        if ($terms): foreach ( $terms as $term ):
        $classesArray[] .= '<span>' . $term->name . '</span>';
        endforeach; endif; 
        $classesArray[] .= '</a>';
        $classesArray[] .= '</li>';
      else :
        // Show nothing
        // $classesArray[] .= 'NO';
      endif;

      // Check if object has term: Saturday
      if (is_object_in_term($class->ID, 'calendar-day', 'saturday') && $day->term_id == 11):
        // $classesArray[] .= 'YES';
        $start_time = get_field('classes_entry_start_time', $class);
        $end_time = get_field('classes_entry_end_time', $class);
        $classesEntry = get_field('classes_entry', $class);
        // Create class item
        $classesArray[] .= '<li>';
        $classesArray[] .= '<a href="' . $classesEntry['booking_app_link'] . '" target="_blank" class="classes-item">';
        $classesArray[] .= '<span>' . $classesEntry['start_time'] . '</span>';
        $classesArray[] .= '<span>' . $class->post_title . '</span>';
        $classesArray[] .= '<span>' . $classesEntry['duration'] . '</span>';
        $terms = get_the_terms( $class->ID , 'calendar-class-type' );
        if ($terms): foreach ( $terms as $term ):
        $classesArray[] .= '<span>' . $term->name . '</span>';
        endforeach; endif; 
        $classesArray[] .= '</a>';
        $classesArray[] .= '</li>';
      else :
        // Show nothing
        // $classesArray[] .= 'NO';
      endif;

      // Check if object has term: Sunday
      if (is_object_in_term($class->ID, 'calendar-day', 'sunday') && $day->term_id == 12):
        // $classesArray[] .= 'YES';
        $start_time = get_field('classes_entry_start_time', $class);
        $end_time = get_field('classes_entry_end_time', $class);
        $classesEntry = get_field('classes_entry', $class);
        // Create class item
        $classesArray[] .= '<li>';
        $classesArray[] .= '<a href="' . $classesEntry['booking_app_link'] . '" target="_blank" class="classes-item">';
        $classesArray[] .= '<span>' . $classesEntry['start_time'] . '</span>';
        $classesArray[] .= '<span>' . $class->post_title . '</span>';
        $classesArray[] .= '<span>' . $classesEntry['duration'] . '</span>';
        $terms = get_the_terms( $class->ID , 'calendar-class-type' );
        if ($terms): foreach ( $terms as $term ):
        $classesArray[] .= '<span>' . $term->name . '</span>';
        endforeach; endif; 
        $classesArray[] .= '</a>';
        $classesArray[] .= '</li>';
      else :
        // Show nothing
        // $classesArray[] .= 'NO';
      endif;


    }

    // Display all queried class results
    $classesTable .= '<ul>' . implode(' ', $classesArray) . '</ul>';

    $classesTable .= '</div>'; // END classes-col
  }

  echo $classesTable;

    wp_die();
}
```